# Verify that all images are loaded in `$(window).load()` function before proceeding

Tags: jquery, slideshow, document-ready

I am adding a number of large images for a slide-show to a page, but I want to start loading these images only when the normal part of the page is completely loaded (including the images).

To do that, I am adding the images in the `$(window).load()` function:

```
var slide_total = 20;

$(window).load(function() {

    for (i = 2; i <= slide_total; i++)
    {
        content = '<li><img src="/images/header' + ((i < 10) ? '0' : '') + i + '.jpg" width="960" height="314"></li>';
        $("#slideshow li:last-child").after(content);
    }

    slide_interval = setInterval( "slideSwitch()", slide_duration );

});
```

The slide-show `slideSwitch()` should start when all images are loaded completely, but as it is now, it starts the moment the elements are added to the DOM.

I cannot move the loop to the `document.ready` function as I don´t want the slide-show to interfere with the loading of the normal images.

How can I check whether all images are loaded before setting the interval?

Comment: window.load definitely waits for everything to load before firing

Comment: @Galen, I know, but as you can see, the images get added in window.load itself, so it has already fired.

Comment: ahh yes, i misunderstood your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// get the total number of images inserted in the DOM
var imgCount = $('#slideshow img').length;

// initialize a counter which increments whenever an image finishes loading
var loadCounter = 0;

// bind to the images' load event
$("#slideshow li img").load(function() {

    // increment the load counter
    loadCounter++;

    // once the load counter equals the total number of images
    // set off the fancy stuff
    if(loadCounter == imgCount) {
        slide_interval = setInterval( "slideSwitch()", slide_duration );
    }
}).each(function() {

    // trigger the load event in case the image has been cached by the browser
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
});
```

Comment: Just to add, I am successfully using the above technique in one of our web apps, which requires that something fires once all images in part of the document have fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work. In IE8 and IE7 the slide-show starts while the images are still loading. Are you sure the jquery `load()` method can be used like that?

Comment: @jeroen - yes, I'm pretty sure :) Are you counting the correct images? I mean, try alerting the image count to ensure it is correct.